# Monte Carlo simulation on sphere: unbiased random steps

Tags: montecarlo

Im doing a Metropolis Monte Carlo simulation with particles on a sphere and have a question concerning the random movement in a given time step.

I understand that to obtain a uniform distribution of random points on the sphere to begin with it is not enough to use the naive simplest way (use spherical coordinates with constant R and pick random angles theta and phi), but one has to for example use one of these methods: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

Looking at another code for a Monte Carlo on a sphere I see a fairly complicated way to generate random moves: pick a random particle, calculate the rotation matrix moving it to the north pole, find a random cartesian vector less than a certain length and move it to the north pole, normalize the cartesian vector and then rotate it back to the vicinity of the original particle position.

This is all to get an unbiased new random position. I don`t understand the rationale completely although I suspect it is connected to detailed balance. But my feeling is that there should be an easier (i.e. faster) way to do this. Actually, intuitively I feel that in this case it is ok to find two small random angles theta and phi and add them to the position of the particle - or would this be a mistake?

Comment: I'm no math guru but it seems to me that if you pick a uniform distribution over theta there should be some distribution you can sample for phi that would give you a uniform sampling over the sphere. EDIT: Also this seems like a pretty math-y question more than a programming one. Perhaps they would be able to answer it at http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Perhaps if we take a tangent surface at the point's present location, perform a uniform random deviation on that surface and then map it back to the sphere?

Comment: @Richard: That is exactly the approximation for small steps he is talking about.

Comment: Thanks for replies! @Aaron: The way I understand what you say you are talking about getting a random distribution over the whole sphere (as in the wolfram link), not moving a small random step.. also I reposted this in the math section like you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rationale behind the algorithm you describe is that the point is mapped to a pole, a tangent plane is generated, a Cartesian vector is generated uniformly in the usual way, this is then mapped back to the sphere, and the rotation is finally reversed. Since the tangent plane is a derivative, for large spheres and small steps this is a good approximation.

Can we do better? Or at least steal someone else's code? Maybe. Consider this: you can already generate a uniform distribution of random points on a sphere, thanks to that [article on MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html).

Without loss of generality, you may consider your current point to be a pole of the sphere. If you use the MathWorld algorithm to generate a random point, you know that the resulting point has uniform probability of being at any azimuthal angle.

The problem is then reduced to finding a bearing on a sphere, given two points' phi/theta values and then generating a new point an incremental surface distance along that bearing's great circle route.

For this new version of the problem, you can get all the code you need by importing your favourite GIS or [projection](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GeodesicCalculations) library and using a spherical model of the Earth (with appropriate scaling).

Many people seem to reference [this site](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Crs) as having a ton of good math on spherical navigation.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunantely I think I didn`t describe the algorithm properly though, it looks to be more something like this: Choose a random 3D vector with a maximum length, move this to the north pole (that is, add [0 0 r]), normalize this point so as to get to the unit sphere, and then rotate this to the vicinity of the original particle position. To me it is a question whether this way of choosing the displacement is uniform, but maybe it is good enough to work for the Monte Carlo. As fof your idea it sounds like a great one, I will try it out!

Comment: Thanks, @jorgen. I'd be very interested in knowing if you find any other answers or insights to this problem - it's an interesting one!

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer the comment above using a comment myself but I can't do that using the limited space reserved for comments. I'm sorry if this abuses the guidelines.

Since you asked and in case someone else ends up here - I do have some new insight into the question:

What we really have to worry about here is detailed balance; if P(a) is the probability to be in state a and P(a->b) is the probability for a transition to state b then detailed balance requires P(a)P(a->b)=P(b)P(b->a).

The metropolis algorithm basically satisfies this by making P(a->b)=1 if P(b)/P(a) > 1 and P(a->b)=P(b)/P(a) otherwise. In my (quantum mechanical) system I use P(a)~|psi(a)|^2, the wavefunction squared (in a statistical mechanics application I guess we would use P(a)~exp[-beta*E]).

The problem with using this on a sphere with steps obtained from a uniform distribution in the angle space {theta,phi}={t,p} is the following: Say we are at a point with a given angle t (the one measuring angle from the north pole along the z axis). From the surface element dS=sin(t) dt dp we see that if our random angle displacements are Dt and Dp the chosen new trial point lies within the area S=4*Dp*sin(Dt)*sin(t), so that the chance to pick a given point p_b is ~1/S ~ 1/sin(t).

Apart from evaluating the |psi(a)|^2 this probability of trying out a given point will of course effect out P(a->b); in fact we see that it will divide the latter with a factor sin(t). Therefore one easy way to conserve detailed balance is to multiply by the same: P(a->b) --> P(a->b)sin(t) where t is the theta-angle of particle a.

This will restore detailed balance. Another question is how this will effect convergence etc, since particles near the poles now have small steplengths but large acceptance probabilities.